# Getting `NoClassDefFoundError` for classes `FutureCallback` and `LazyList` using Jetty Maven plugin 9.4.32.v20200930 on Java 11

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty

I started a few months ago to maintain an old Spring project using the Jetty Maven plugin. I'm currently trying to port it to Java 11 but Jetty won't start the server and (silently) fails with `MultiException[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/FutureCallback, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/LazyList]`.

This seems to be an old bug of the Jetty Maven plugin that I can reproduce on various `9.x` versions.

It seems fixed in versions 10 and 11 and I would gladly use these versions but both are still in alpha, configuration has radically changed and documentation is not published yet.

`maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` are both set to *11* in POM and nothing changes if I put dependencies providing `org.eclipse.jetty.util.FutureCallback` and `org.eclipse.jetty.util.LazyList` in the POM.

```
[WARNING] FAILED ServletHandler@4ba402b5{FAILED}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/LazyList
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/LazyList
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doStop (ServletHandler.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop (ContainerLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop (ContainerLifeCycle.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop (AbstractHandler.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStop (SecurityHandler.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStop (ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop (ContainerLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop (ContainerLifeCycle.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop (AbstractHandler.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStop (SessionHandler.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop (ContainerLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop (ContainerLifeCycle.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop (AbstractHandler.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.stopContext (ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.stopContext (ServletContextHandler.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.stopWebapp (JettyWebAppContext.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopContext (WebAppContext.java:1428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop (ContextHandler.java:1115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop (ServletContextHandler.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop (WebAppContext.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStop (JettyWebAppContext.java:433)
```

Comment: Can you give some more information including the exception stacktrace and a server dump (see https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-server-dump.html).

Comment: @Lachlan Sure! Here is the full stack trace: https://pastebin.com/qyBXEs6n

Comment: And here is the dump: https://pastebin.com/rfeWrg97

Answer (score 0):

This is a interesting side-effect of interaction between maven and jetty.

What happens is that on jetty stop/shutdown the maven process yanks the classloader out from underneath the jetty threads leaving random errors in its wake, some even being unable to find classes that they need to perform a clean shutdown.

See https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4410

There is no workaround or fix for this that either Jetty or Maven has found.

If you find a solution please comment on the above issue (or file a new issue), and we'll document it.

Comment: You mean this error only happens on Jetty shutdown? So it's not the reason why the project starts but then immediately stops?

Comment: Correct.  The issue I mentioned, and your stacktrace, is only produced on stop/shutdown of the Jetty server.

Comment: Ok, I'm back to the starting point. But thanks a lot helping me sorting this out.

Comment: The reason your server fails to start is currently silent, no useful feedback.  Perhaps you should detail what you are attempting to do in your (next) question.  what your configuration on jetty-maven-plugin looks like, etc ...   It's likely either a misconfiguration or a misuse.